# Retrieve data from couchdb (how to verify that a value is in a database)

Tags: python, nosql, couchdb, cloudant

how can I retrieve data from a couchdb database, not in a document of a database but in all the documents of the database.  I already verified if a value was in a document but I want now to verify if a value is in a special database.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to be specific here, since you're not providing any example data. Do you mean if a particular value exists *anywhere* in any document, or if a specific field holds a specific value in any document?

If you mean the former, I'd advice you to come up with a better data model. So let's focus on the latter. Let's say your documents contain the field called `special`, and you want to know if any such documents has the value 99 in this field:

```
{
    ...
    "special": 99
}
```

Create a view keyed on the value:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc && doc.special) {
    emit(doc.special, null);
  }
}
```

Now you can check if documents exist in this database for values of the special field:

```
# Look for the value 99
% acurl 'https://XYZ.cloudant.com/aaa/_design/test/_view/special?key=99'  
{"total_rows":3,"offset":2,"rows":[
   {"id":"a3c424e99f3cc9988a2553bb680ac7f8","key":99,"value":null}
]}
```

In my databse `aaa` there is one document, with the id `a3c424e9...` that has the value 99 in the `special` field. This is a so-called reverse index.

Comment: First of all thank you to have answered.  So, Yeah I want to verify if a value is in any document of the database but in python with the library couchdb.

Comment: A client library is just a veneer on top of the couchdb http api. The process will be the same. Create the view. Query the view for the value you wish to see if present.